# C# Regex on large file, partial completion or get percentage done

Tags: c#, regex

I was wondering if there was any way to get any statistics from a Regex object while it is looking for matches.

I have a really large text file (+800kb) that I'm matching a fairly complex regex and it takes 2-5 mins to complete on some of the files.  Is there any way I can break the document down into smaller chunks?  Or is there a way to get the percentage done so I can know about how much time I have left?

Thanks :)

Comment: "break the document down into smaller chunks": it's necessary, but only you can know how to split into smaller chunks. The simplest way could be to split line by line the file, but it depends what your files contains

Comment: "I have a really large text file (+800kb)" -- what are you running this on that this is big?

Comment: Can your regex match more than one line?

Comment: [1982 called and wants its definition of "really large text file" back.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_floppy_disk)

Comment: a 1 mb text file > 100 pages of printed text.  idk, I think that's "really large text file".  The largest is ~450  pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anyway for you to predict a superset that can define a chunk (guaranteed to not break a regular expression)? i.e, do you know of a separator within the file which will not be caught within your regex? if not, I think you might not be able to do that.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  Not only did it speed up the search, but then was able to do percentages.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does your regex need to be applied to the whole file as one string, or could you apply it a line at a time? That would let you give progress in a reasonably obvious way, although you'd need to read *all* the lines to start with of course in order to give the progress as a *proportion* rather than just "completed N lines".

I don't believe there's any way of asking an already-executing regex what its progress is.

Comment: If holding the all the lines in memory is not feasible (800kb doesn't seem to be the case, though), you can keep a running total of the number of bytes in the lines processed so far, and use the ratio between that and the filesize.

Comment: I do need to apply the regex to the whole file.  It's a PDF with lots of formatting.  I did find a way to parse it into recurring chunks and then run the regex on those chuncks.  Thanks for the help thou!

Answer (score 0):

You're running the regex on the entire file at once? If you are, then no. If you're running it line-by-line, just keep a counter of which line you're on, then every so often print out the line number.